# Azure App Service Linux Container: File Share Not Writeable

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage-files

As per title, I have created an Azure App Service running a tomcat image (docker container).
When I have set up the path map to a FIle Share, the container or tomcat keeps on complaining that the folder that I mounted into the container itself is not writeable....

I read on Azure's website that File Share's mounted is Read/Write => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-serve-content-from-azure-storage

So I'm confused as to why it's still not working.... Any help would be really appreciated with this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you mounted the storage in your dockerfile, drop your snippet if possible, but I simply made the `WORKDIR` match the mount path. My dockerfile was a node app but shouldn't make a difference and realized that I didn't need the `VOLUME` keyword (it's commented).

[image]